# Hitting a url better?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a `ashx` handler which outputs the file, when pinged.
As of now, I have it working by

```
window.open('url to ping');
```

I'm happy with the result. But however I'm interested in a better solution, since a user might have turned on popup blocker, which might result in file not downloading.
I can also use jquery ( *if that helps* )

Comment: Why are you using `window.open`? Couldn't you just link to the URL with a standard hyperlink? Also, you keep saying *ping*. I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @Yuck I don't want user to click on a hyperlink. I know that already. And when i mean ping, i mean to hit the url, so the file gets downloaded automatically without any user interaction.

Comment: @Yuck i am using `window.open()` since it hits the url and so the file gets downloaded.

Comment: What's the context in which you're calling `window.open`? There must be some action taken by the user before you're invoking that method.

Comment: no, i'm polling the server to see if a user has got a file, and if yes, then I make it download.

Comment: Can't you just use `window.location` instead? You won't lose the current page because the browser will see the content type and download the file instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `window.location = "http://pathtoyourhandler.ashx"` instead.

With appropriate `Content-Type` the browser will stay on the current page and begin downloading the requested file.

Comment: I have `application/zip` as my content type. Will that work ?

Comment: Yes. It's the same as if you copied a link to a file in your browser by hand. There is no "page" to display, so the browser just downloads whatever is found at the URL instead.

Comment: can you answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278310/hitting-a-url-better/22278435?noredirect=1#comment-33843582 which is a comment from plalx ?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want a window to open, you could always create a hidden `<iframe>` that has it's `src` property set to your link.

We used that work around when simply setting the location did not give the expected result (at least in IE8).

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NW3YL/)

Comment: @AmitJoki It worked in every browser I tried so far, in which one did you test? We used that work around at work because simply setting `window.location` did not provide the desired result in every situation (but we were still on IE8).

Comment: I tried $('<iframe src="url" />') in the latest chrome but the file didn't download.

Comment: @AmitJoki That's because you also need to add the it to the DOM.

Comment: @AmitJoki Well if the other solution works for you dont even bother, I will just delete this answer ;)

Comment: @AmitJoki Works well for me in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/NW3YL/ However like I said, I prefer the other answer if it also works.

Comment: @AmitJoki My answer is not better, it is an alternative to the other solution proposed where setting `window.location` would fail to produce the expected result (e.g would still affect the current view). When I posted the answer I simply assumed that you already tried setting `window.location`.